# SQL Query: LIKE x%

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have a problem with my SQL Query and I would kindly ask for help.

I have rows like:

```
2% 

20%

a 20% b

a 2 b

a 2% b

etc.
```

I want to see only those that contain '2%' inside the string.

When I wanted to filter them using:

```
WHERE ColA LIKE '%2%%'
```

it showed all above rows, instead of only:

```
2%

a 2% b
```

Could you help me with it?

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
WHERE ColA LIKE '%2[%]%'
```

Comment: This is highly database specific.  It only works in SQL Server, and the OP has not specified the database.

Answer (score 3):

% matches any string in SQL, you have to escape the %. You can do this by defining an escape character in the same command:

```
WHERE ColA LIKE '%2/%%' ESCAPE '/';
```

Comment: This is the ANSI standard and should work in most databases.